# macro references execution in call execute

Tags: sas

SAS documentation says the macro references in call execute are executed immediately. Does this code exemplify it?

```
 %let var = abc;

 data _null_;
   call execute ('&var');
 run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of. Here is a more complete example using value of the macro variable that is actual executable SAS code.

```
data _null_;
  call symputx('var','data;run;');
run;

%put var= %superq(var);

data _null_;
  call execute ('&var');
run;
```

You can see in the SAS log that the code that CALL EXECUTE() actually pushed onto the stack to run is the VALUE of the macro variable even though the single quotes would prevent the macro variable from expanding during the data _null_ step that is using the CALL EXECUTE() statement.

```
NOTE: CALL EXECUTE generated line.
1    + data;run;
```

Comment: Tom, how does single and double quotes on argument of CALL EXECUTE() act?

Comment: If you use double quotes then macro variable references are resolved so the actual command that the data step will run would be `call execute("data;run;");` in which case there is no macro variable reference for the CALL EXECUTE to evaluate.